# Does "df['var'].map(df2)" and "df.var.map(df2)" always produce the same result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `var`, and another dataframe `df2` with columns `var` and `var2`. Both columns `var` in 2 dataframes are exactly the same.

In my example, `df['var'].map(df2)` and `df.var.map(df2)` yield the same result. I would like to ask if this is just a coincidence in my particular dataset, or it always holds.

Thank you so much!

**Update:** In my example, these below codes also produce the same result.

```
df.groupby('parent_id')['parent_id'].transform('count').tolist()
```

and

```
df.groupby('parent_id').parent_id.transform('count').tolist()
```

This gives me a feeling that `df.groupby('parent_id')['parent_id']` and `df.groupby('parent_id').parent_id` produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (as long as the column exists in your data). It's syntactic sugar called *attribute access*. See the pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access).